# ASP.NET MVC & Windsor.Castle: working with HttpContext-dependent services

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have several dependency injection services which are dependent on stuff like HTTP context. Right now I'm configuring them as **singletons** the Windsor container in the Application_Start handler, which is obviously a problem for such services.

What is the best way to handle this? I'm considering making them **transient** and then releasing them after each HTTP request. But what is the best way/place to inject the HTTP context into them? Controller factory or somewhere else?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Castle Windsor you can use the `PerWebRequest` lifetime - that should fit pretty well with your requirements.

That means you can just inject the HTTP stuff into your services, and the container will take care of the proper lifetime management. However, this requires you to also register all these services (and all consumers of those services and so on) as PerWebRequest (or Transient) because if you register them as Singletons, they will hold on to stale (and possibly disposed) contexts.

Comment: Mark, thanks for the info - I didn't know about PerWebRequest. I'll check it out.

Comment: Mark, I've looked into PerWebRequest, but I still don't see how services can obtain HttpContext. When I try to register an instance of HttpContextBase it in the container myself, it fails after the second request (since an instance was already registered in the previous request). I couldn't find anything on Google so far...

Comment: I may have misunderstood what you are trying to do, but you can't use the HttpContext from Application_Start because at this point there *is* no HttpContext (PerWebRequest or no PerWebRequest). Now that I think about it, it makes no sense to attempt to control the lifetime of the HttpContext from the DI Container, since this lifetime is already being managed by the ASP.NET MVC framework. What you *can* do is to hook into a custom IControllerFactory and grab the HttpContext served to you at that point, and then use a factory method to wire up everything else that depends on it.

Comment: Mark: a colleague of mine suggested accessing HttpContext.Current property, without injection or factory methods. It's not very DI-friendly, but it looks like it works. I've registered these services as PerWebRequest, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 25):

Just like Mark said, you need to register these http-dependent services either as PerWebRequest or Transient. Here's a sample that shows how to register and inject a HttpRequest or HttpContext:

```
public class Service {
    private readonly HttpRequestBase request;

    public Service(HttpRequestBase request) {
        this.request = request;
    }

    public string RawUrl {
        get {
            return request.RawUrl;
        }
    }
}

...

protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    IWindsorContainer container = new WindsorContainer();
    container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();
    container.AddComponentLifeStyle<Service>(LifestyleType.Transient);

  container.Register(Component.For<HttpRequestBase>()
      .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
      .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpRequestWrapper(HttpContext.Current.Request)));

  container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>()
      .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
      .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));  
}
```

By using `HttpRequestBase` instead of `HttpRequest` you can easily mock it out for testing.
Also, don't forget to register `PerWebRequestLifestyleModule` in your web.config.

Comment: Thanks Mauricio, this is something I was looking for.

Comment: Might be worth reiterating that you need to add the line:

container.AddFacility<FactorySupportFacility>();

This was a small gotcha for me that I missed off your example on first reading. Thanks for the help, very useful!

Comment: As of Windsor 2.5, `FactorySupportFacility` is not required anymore for this case.

Comment: But all components depending on the HTTP context needs to be registered as PerWebRequest or transient, right? Is it possible to avoid that?

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this exact same problem, but my solution is somewhat different.

Interface:

```
public interface IHttpContextProvider
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the current HTTP context.
    /// </summary>
    /// <value>The current HTTP context.</value>
    HttpContextBase Current { get; }
}
```

Implementation:

```
/// <summary>
/// A default HTTP context provider, returning a <see cref="HttpContextWrapper"/> from <see cref="HttpContext.Current"/>.
/// </summary>
public class DefaultHttpContextProvider : IHttpContextProvider
{
    public HttpContextBase Current
    {
        get { return new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current); }
    }
}
```

I then register the `IHttpContextProvider` as a singleton in the container.
I'm still a bit of a newbie when it comes to DI, so maybe I'm over complicating things, but from what I can understand, I can't have any singleton components depend on PerWebRequest lifestyle components, which makes sense (but that's what all examples do). In my solution, I depend on `HttpContext.Current` in an isolated component and I'm not interested in testing that. But every component that needs access to the HTTP context can get that by depending on `IHttpContextProvider` and easily mock that as needed.

Am I really over complicating things or are there any caveats in my solution?

Comment: I should mention, that in this way, none of my services that depend on the current HTTP context needs to be registered as PerWebRequest/Transient.