# Register .net MVC3 ControllerContext into windsor container

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor

With ASP.NET MVC3 what would be the best way to register the requests ControllerContext into castle windsor container? Ultimately I'd like to be able to say

```
container.Resolve<ControllerContext>();
```

and have the requests controller context returned.

### More detail

The vast majority of my actions are just going to do some validation, authentication, etc.. before sending a message to nservicebus to actually do the work.  To avoid having to copy/paste these 20/30 lines of code all over the place I have put them into a handler class which my controllers take a dependency on in the constructor, the actions then call this class which leaves my actions containing just one line of code.

One of the child classes that makes up the handler needs to know about the route that was taken, I could just pass the controller to the handler and then onto this class but it seems a bit messy.  It would be nice if there was a way to get Windsor registered to provide it for me.

Comment: Where do you want to inject the ControllerContext? It normally just belongs to the controller.

Comment: Response was a bit too long for comments so i've edited the original post instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can register the ControllerContext without some very ugly hacks, and IMHO it's not a good idea anyway. The ControllerContext belongs to the controller, it's not meant to be shared around.

However, if you only need the routing information, you can register it like this (UNTESTED!):

```
container.Register(Component.For<HttpContextBase>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextBaseWrapper(HttpContext.Current))
                    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest,
                   Component.For<RouteData>()
                    .UsingFactoryMethod(k => RouteTable.Routes.GetRouteData(k.Resolve<HttpContextBase>()))
                    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest);
```

Also see [ASP.NET MVC & Windsor.Castle: working with HttpContext-dependent services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818888/asp-net-mvc-windsor-castle-working-with-httpcontext-dependent-services/1856427#1856427) for more details.

I don't know concretely what you're trying to achieve but I'd look into doing it with filters or custom ActionResults instead.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to the original question but I can't stand dubious architectural moves :) It seems for me like ControllerContext isn't a best (well, not even a good one) place to try to extend from. The ModelBinders and ActionAttributes are the places to help with repeating code. They can take model mapping, binding and validation on their own thus freeing controllers from that responsibility.

Well, generally, what you'd really want to do is to use Dependency Injection for Controllers themselves injecting configured instances of somewhat **IAuthenticationService** and **IValidationService** (concrete implementations of them would contain all those 20/30 reusable lines of code). Then in Controllers you just call them in one line of code (or even use the MVC3 Global Filters feature to make that completely transparent).