# HttpContextBase: Session is null

Tags: session, castle-windsor, httpcontext

I use Windor Castle to wrap the **HttpContext** into a **HttpContextWrapper** via a **factory method**.

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<HttpContextBase>()
        .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
        .UsingFactoryMethod(() => new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current)));
```

I have a class called `SessionStorage` which accesses `HttpContext.Current.Session`. I register it this way:

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<ISessionStorage>()
    .LifeStyle.PerWebRequest
    .ImplementedBy<HttpSessionStorage>());
```

The `HttpSessionStorage` class:

```cs
public class HttpSessionStorage : ISessionStorage
{
    public HttpContextBase httpContext { get; set; }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        httpContext.Session.Remove(key);        
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)httpContext.Session[key];
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        httpContext.Session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

When I use it this way, then in **about 40%** of the cases the **`Session` property is null** and ***only*** if the **requests are at a very high rate**.

The strange thing is that if I use `HttpContext.Current` **instead of** `httpContext`, it works in all cases.

```cs
public class HttpSessionStorage : ISessionStorage
{
    public HttpContextBase httpContext { get; set; }

    public void Remove(string key)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Remove(key);        
    }

    public T Get<T>(string key)
    {
        return (T)HttpContext.Current.Session[key];
    }

    public void Set<T>(string key, T value)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session[key] = value;
    }
}
```

It has something to do with Windsor Castle but I can't find the problem. I registered everything I can as `PerWebRequest` (except a NHibernate session factory).

Does someone have an idea what else I could check?

Lg
warappa

Comment: Can you define "very high rate of requests"? Can you post a failing test? Have you tried making it transient instead of PerWebRequest?

Comment: "Very high rate of requests": a ImageController has to serve ~25 images. Everytime a request is made to any controller (so this one too), a principal is created and stored in session (through HttpSessionStorage). Like said, sometimes the save fails because the session in the session in the wrapper is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, it wasn't due to inproper Castle Windsor registration but something simpler: I **accessed Session** at a time when it's **not garanteed to be fully initialized** - dummy me!

My solution was to move the Session accessing code from `Application_BeginRequest` to `Application_AcquireRequestState` like [pointed out here](http://forums.asp.net/t/889130.aspx/1?global%20asax%20cs%20Context%20Session%20null%20).

Note:
Maybe this code should be moved into a base controller - in OnAuthorization (**edit**: it works!).

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems a while back, maybe the answers to my question can help you: [ASP.NET MVC & Windsor.Castle: working with HttpContext-dependent services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818888/asp-net-mvc-windsor-castle-working-with-httpcontext-dependent-services)